# How to get a resource path as a string from the project folder - WP7

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, windows-phone-7

I have this XML file, which I am trying to deserialize.

How can I get the path to the resource file, when its in my project's root?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var rs = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("1.xml", UriKind.Relative));
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rs.Stream);
string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

1.xml must be saved as Content. For Resource type Uri will be different

Comment: I know I can stream it, but how do I deserialize it then? I can't just put the StreamReader to the deserializer.

Comment: XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(serializedObject));
serializedObject o = serializer.Deserialize(rs.Stream);    Don't forget to reference System.Xml.Serialization